# Spring Boot: Logback Issue with Owasp ESAPI version 2.2.3.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, owasp

I've recently started looking at how to sanitise any user inputs to my test api and I came across this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-prevent-xss)

Before attempting the tutorial I had logging to console with GCP cloud as thats where I want to run my API.

Now after adding owasp esapi my application will not start when using version 2.2.3.1 of esapi. I just by sure luck attempted using a previous version and it works as in the application will start.

Below is the error I get from logback on application start up

```
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory loaded from file:/Users/xxx/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.30/e606eac955f55ecf1d8edcccba04eb8ac98088dd/slf4j-simple-1.7.30.jar). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml: org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory
```

Again, If I use version 2.2.2.0 I have no issues at all on startup. Can anyone with experience shed some light here. (PLEASE SEE EDIT)

Below is my gradle build file (note I'm also using GCP logging)

```
plugins {
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.5.0"
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "idea"
    id 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib' version '3.0.0'
}
group 'network.thefullstack.search-service'
version '1.0'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_14
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_14
}

jib.from.image = 'openjdk:15-jdk-buster'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security'
    testImplementation group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-test'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-oauth2-client'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch')
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-elasticsearch'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-validation'

    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-gcp-starter-logging'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-gcp-starter-logging', version: '1.2.8.RELEASE'

    implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '3.0.0'
    implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-boot-starter', version: '3.0.0'

    implementation group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.1.Final'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.11.2'

    implementation group: 'org.openapitools', name: 'jackson-databind-nullable', version: '0.2.1'
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
    implementation group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20210307'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.4'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.11'

    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.13.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0'
    implementation 'org.owasp:dependency-check-gradle:6.1.6'
    compile (group: 'org.owasp.esapi', name: 'esapi', version: '2.2.2.0')

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }

    jar {
        manifest {
            attributes(
                    'Main-Class': 'org.test.SearchServiceApplication'
            )
        }
        from {
            configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my ESAPI.properties file:

```
ESAPI.Logger=org.owasp.esapi.logging.slf4j.Slf4JLogFactory
```

Here is an example of where I am logging:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class StringToEnumConverter implements Converter<String, Filters> {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StringToEnumConverter.class);

    @Override
    public Filters convert(String source) {
        try {
            logger.info("Attempting to convert ENUM param to uppercase {}", source);
            return Filters.valueOf(source.toUpperCase());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.error("Failed to convert ENUM param to uppercase {}", source);
            throw new BadFilterRequestException("Error: Filter provide must be one of: " + Arrays.asList(Filters.values()), "Search");
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Using the older version while it will allow the API to start, it will fire this error message when its envoked:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.owasp.esapi.logging.slf4j.Slf4JLogFactory
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
    at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.loadClassByStringName(ObjFactory.java:158)
    at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:81)
    at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.logFactory(ESAPI.java:139)
    at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.getLogger(ESAPI.java:155)
    at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder.<init>(DefaultEncoder.java:83)
    at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder.getInstance(DefaultEncoder.java:67)
    ... 46 common frames omitted
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Have you got any fix for this?

Comment: No @Sankar but it looks like this lib is no longer maintained. I'm now looking for alternatives.

Comment: Please let me know once you got.